# Best way to save video in iOS Application for offline viewing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm in state of confusion that **"What would be the best way to store video?"** locally downloaded from the server.

I have two versions of same app i.e online and other offline. 
For offline mode I want to download all the videos locally for watching them offline in future.
I know that there are two ways of storing videos:

1. Feasible way would be storing it in document directory of the application and save the corresponding video file name in the sqlite database. But, **there are around 200+ videos!**
   I just fear it might create memory problem, giving my application memory warning and make it to crash.
2. Storing it in `NSData` format in sqlite database, but it would make the database huge which I think would not be feasible as sqlite db is meant to be light weight.

Is there some other way that we can accomplish the task. (And as per the requirement videos should not be save in the gallery on the device).

Please help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the document directory is your only option. It should not effect the memory, however, please keep in mind that if you app gets deleted, this directory will be as well.

I have recently built an app that relied on saving videos to the Document directory and we ran in to no problems.

I would avoid storing large assets in a Database. You gain no benefit from this and these videos will still be lost if the app is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can save any kind of files, anywhere in your application environment directories using...

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:[/*Your current file path*/] toPath:/*Your destination path*/ error:/* &errorObj */];
```

**OR**

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[/*Your current file path*/] toPath:/*Your destination path*/ error:/* &errorObj */];
```

and for moving 200+ files... you can use a naming convention from which you can handle it using any kind of loops.

***Note :***

*1. For any kind of large in size files, I always use this way, rather than saving in any kind* *of databases.*

*2. One should always use "move" operation while downloading the files.*